# Downloading a file from http site to my local file using SSIS?

Tags: batch-file, ssis

Its soounds simple but proving to be a headache . How can i do this ? My initial idea was to use a bat file and then add it as a task in SSIS .

Problem is that copy, xcopy or robcopy does not work ?

robocopy "http://wpcfs.corp.xx.com/xxx/xxx/BEP/xxx/documents/EB%20Bus%20Ops%20Points%20of%20Contact.xlsx" "C:\Imports\"

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to download from a website then you can use a SSIS script to download the files either via WebClient, WebRequest, or through the HTTP Connection Manager.  There's a pretty thorough example of downloading via the HTTP Connection Manager [on this blog](http://www.sqlis.com/post/Downloading-a-file-over-HTTP-the-SSIS-way.aspx).  The blog comments also includes code that I listed below that downloads the data via WebRequest/WebResponse.  You could also use the more straight forward WebClient, but I found I had problems using the WebClient to download really large files that I was able to avoid with the WebRequest/WebResponse approach.

```
Imports System.IO 
Imports System.Net 
Imports System.Text 
Imports System.Web 


Public Class WebRetrieve 
    Public Shared Sub Main() 

       Dim wr As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://reports/reports.txt"), HttpWebRequest)

        Dim ws As HttpWebResponse = CType(wr.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse) 
        Dim str As Stream = ws.GetResponseStream() 
        Dim inBuf(100000000) As Byte 
        Dim bytesToRead As Integer = CInt(inBuf.Length) 
        Dim bytesRead As Integer = 0 
        While bytesToRead > 0 
            Dim n As Integer = str.Read(inBuf, bytesRead, bytesToRead) 
            If n = 0 Then 
                Exit While 
            End If 
            bytesRead += n 
            bytesToRead -= n 
        End While 
        Dim fstr As New FileStream("c:\New\reports.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
         fstr.Write(inBuf, 0, bytesRead) 
        str.Close() 
        fstr.Close() 
    End Sub 
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wget for windows to download the file

check [this](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)

after installing wget,

```
wget URL
```

will download the file in current directory